# Is it possible to have a class member array with template elements

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, stack

I wonder if it is possible to have a class member array with template elements. What I want to do is something like the following.

```
#ifndef _STACK_H_
#define _STACK_H_

#include <exception>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class stack
{
 public:
  stack();
  void push(T data);
  void pop();
  T top();
  bool is_empty();
  bool is_full();

 private:
  int elem_max;
  int elem_num;
  T elem_array[elem_max];


};
#include "stack.template.cc"

#endif
```

and then in my main program to have something like:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  stack<int> one;
  one.push(10);
  return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don’t you try it? Yes, it’s possible.

Comment: Re **`_STACK_H_`**, names starting with underscore followed by uppercase letter are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: It's possible, but you'll need to rethink `elem_max` in your example above.

Comment: Also, to avoid inadvertent name conflicts (like, conflict with `std::distance`), it's a good idea to not (read: "never") put `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header.

Comment: Finally (this may border on information overflow?), it's a good idea to add a `const` at the end of a pure accessor member function, like `bool is_empty() const`. This way such function can be called on a `const` object. Thus increasing the usefulness of the class. :-)

Comment: Thank you.
Is it possible to have data of different types in the same T elem_array[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename T,size_t MAX_CAPACITY=16> //change 16 to whatever you want
class stack
{
public:
    stack();
    void push(const T &data);
    void pop();
    T& top();
    const T& top()const;
    bool is_empty()const;
    bool is_full()const;

private:
    size_t elem_num;
    T elem_array[MAX_CAPACITY];
};

int main()
{
    stack<int> one; //stack of ints with maximum capacity of 16
    one.push(10);

    stack<int,1024> two; //stack of ints with maximum capacity of 1024
    two.push(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is it possible to have data of different types in the same T elem_array[]?

Comment: @Cooli nope they all have to be of the same type unless T=some_base_class* then the array can have some_base_class* in it and some_derived_class* in it as well. Also if this was the answer you were looking for could you please choose it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, since template is evaluate before the class is instanced. Why not test it with your compiler?

```
template <typename T>
class Stack
{
    static const size_t MAX_STACK = 1024; 
    T m_Buffer[MAX_STACK]; 
public:
    // ...
};
```

compiles without problems.

The main problem is, you need the size of the array determined at COMPILE TIME, not RUNTIME. Here I used a `static const` to make it work. If you want a flexible array, consider using `std::vector` or `std::list` or so.

Comment: In order to avoid unintended text substitution it's a good idea to reserve ALL UPPERCASE for macro names, and to use that for all macro names, since that's now the common convention. Using this convention for constants is a Java-thing, originating with early C which didn't have `const` so that constants had to be defined as macros. Oh the irony...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Even in C you cannot use `const int A=10; int b[A];` because C `const` mechanism is different from C++ `const` mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is it possible to have data of different types in the same T elem_array[]?